# Convert Set[Range] to Set[Int] in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to get set difference between two sets as follows:

```
val set1 = Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
// gives:  scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
val set2 = Set(0 until 10)
// gives:  scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.collection.immutable.Range]
```

However,  the following gives error:

```
scala> set2.diff(set1)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
required: scala.collection.GenSet[scala.collection.immutable.Range]
      set2.diff(set1)
                ^
```

How to convert  `Set[Range]`  to `Set[Int]`  in easiest way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could  do this:

```
(0 to 10).toSet
```

or to stick with your initial idea (but less clean):

```
Set(0 until 10).flatten
```

which returns:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(0, 5, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)
```

If you worked with a list you could do this (it doesn't seem to work for a Set):

```
List.range(0, 10)
```

Comment: Yes, there is no `Set.range()` but you can do `val set2 = collection.GenSet.range(0, 10)` The `diff()` will work on either/both `Set` types.

Comment: Indeed, interesting and it does answer the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the answer suggested above

```
(0 until 10).toSet
```

also works and returns the same.